# How to get dependent objects

Tags: java, hibernate, object

I'm trying to get the accounts existing in a bank, but the list is empty even though the link between the two exist in the database.
Knowing that the interaction between the database and my program works fine, except that bank.getAccounts() returns an empty list.
here is my code.
What i'm trying to do is:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bank bank = new Bank();
    bank.setName("XXX");
    bank.setStreet("XXX");
    bank.setPc("XXX");
    bank.save();

    Account c = new account();
    c.setBalance(10);
    c.setBank(bank);
    c.save();

    account c2 = new account();
    c2.setBalance(20);
    c2.setBank(bank);
    c2.save();

    for(account c : bank.getAccounts())
        System.out.println("account n°: " + c.getId() + ", balance: " + c.getBalance());



}

}
```

The Bank class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANK")
public class Bank implements Serializable {


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8199961750065782869L;

static private BankDAO dao;

private long id;
private String name;
private String street;
private String pc;

private Set<Account> accounts;

public Bank() {
    super();
    this.accounts = new HashSet<>();
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getPc() {
    return pc;
}

public void setPc(String pc) {
    this.pc = pc;
}



@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="bank")
public Set<Account> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(Set<Account> accounts) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
}

// Equals and hashCode implementations deleted

@Transient
private BankDAO getDao() {
    if(Bank.dao == null)
        dao = BankDAO.getDAO();
    return Bank.dao;
}


public long save() {
    Bank.dao = this.getDao();
    return dao.save(this);
}


public int delete() {
    Bank.dao = this.getDao();
    return dao.delete(this);
}   
}
```

The Accounts class code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7224745445343369682L;

static private AccountDAO dao;

public long id;
public int balance;
public Bank bank;

public Account() {
    super();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="bank_id", nullable=false)
@Id
public Bank getBank() {
    return bank;
}

public void setBank(Bank bank) {
    this.bank = bank;
}

@Transient
private AccountDAO getDao() {
    if(Account.dao == null)
        dao = AccountDAO.getDAO();
    return Account.dao;
}

/*
 * save the state of the object: save or update
 * @return: the id of the object
 */
public long save() {
    Account.dao = this.getDao();
    return dao.save(this);
}


public int delete() {
    Account.dao = this.getDao();
    return dao.delete(this);
}
}
```

Log is:

```
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:54 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:54 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:54 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernateDataBase]
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@67080771
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): business.Account
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:55 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): business.Account
Hibernate: alter table ACCOUNT drop constraint FKc0nxjvf82u84r0b01m367tss3Feb 13, 2018 11:38:56 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@10650953] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.

Hibernate: drop table if exists BANK cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists ACCOUNT cascade
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:56 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@7db82169] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table BANK (id int8 not null, pc varchar(255), name varchar(255), street varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table ACCOUNT (id int8 not null, balance int4 not null, bank_id int8 not null, primary key (id, bank_id))
Hibernate: alter table ACCOUNT add constraint FKc0nxjvf82u84r0b01m367tss3 foreign key (bank_id) references BANK
Feb 13, 2018 11:38:56 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@3276732'
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into BANK (pc, name, street, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select account_.id, account_.bank_id, account_.balance as balance2_1_ from ACCOUNT account_ where account_.id=? and account_.bank_id=?
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into ACCOUNT (balance, id, bank_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select account_.id, account_.bank_id, account_.balance as balance2_1_ from ACCOUNT account_ where account_.id=? and account_.bank_id=?
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into ACCOUNT (balance, id, bank_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: What sql / hql is being logged? Have you tried running the query against your database "by hand"?

Comment: no, of course not by hand.I'll add the log on the post, actually the call of hibernate methode are in DAO classes.

Comment: What happens if you fetch the bank again before iterating? Could it be a cache problem?

Comment: if i fetch again, nothing happens, but there is one more line in the log: Hibernate: select bank0_.id as id1_0_0_, bank0_.cp as pc2_0_0_, banque0_.name as name3_0_0_, bank0_.street as street4_0_0_, accounts1_.bank_id as bank_i3_1_1_, accounts1_.id as id1_1_1_, accounts1_.id as id1_1_2_, accounts1_.bank_id as bank_i3_1_2_, accounts1_.balance as balance2_1_2_ from BANK bank0_ left outer join ACCOUNT accounts1_ on bank0_.id=accounts1_.bank_id where bank0_.id=?

Answer (score 0):

```
Bank bank = new Bank();
bank.setName("XXX");
bank.setStreet("XXX");
bank.setPc("XXX");
bank.save(); -- checkpoint 1

Account c = new account();
c.setBalance(10);
c.setBank(bank); -- checkpoint 2
c.save();

account c2 = new account();
c2.setBalance(20);
c2.setBank(bank);
c2.save(); -- checkpoint 3
```

It wont work that way as as you can see @ checkpioint 1 you have you Bank object and nothing will change its state. I gues you would like to Bank->account poulate by checkpoint 2 and 3 but this is not going to happen.

What you have to do is to put that relations manually by simply

```
bank.getAccounts().add(c1);
```

However in order to relations to work like you would expect (as bank is already initialized so no lazy fetch will occure), you need to actually fetch your bank again via eg query. Then, newly returned bank will have unitialized collections proxies and will indeed perform additional select (if not eager fetch specified) to get collections of accounts associated with that bank.

Comment: I have no problem with fetching again, except even when i fetch again, the collection i get is empty, that's my problem, i don't wanna populate it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
i was using find(id) method to fetch the bank from the database, when i use load(id) or get(id) it works fine.
Best regards.